# How to Restore Win Drive Permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions, windows-command-prompt

I've been playing with my C: drive permissions and I have managed to mess them up.  Now when I log in nothing appears and I can't launch anything.  I tried safe mode and the same thing happens with that.

I can't even launch cmd.exe and it says that "I don't have the permissions" even though I am the admin.

I tried to use the command prompt in repair mode but when I choose the language it says the Parameter is incorrect and then restarts.

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 with AD installed on it.  What should I do?

Comment: [MSKB - *"How do I restore security settings to a known working state?"*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313222/en-us)

Comment: On an AD server: "I've been playing with my C drive permissions...", haha.

Comment: Honestly? Reinstall / Restore from Backup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should restore your server from your latest backup.

Comment: tnx but i dont have a backup

Comment: Then you are in trouble. Start rebuilding.

Comment: don't use the b-word!!!

Answer (score 1):

I missed the bit on "I cannot launch cmd.exe". So this is not going to help you.

you could try icacls.exe with the /reset switch from the root of c:

```
cd /d c:
icacls * /t/ /q /c /reset
```

the /t switch if for recursively change permsisions.
The /q is for quiet, the /c is to continue on errors.

you may have to take ownership of the files first

```
takeown /R /F *
```

Comment: /reset only removes implicit entries and replaces them with inheritable entries. It sounds like the OP broke permissions at the root of the volume, so this likely won't help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

1. Boot your server off the install CD.
2. Choose Repair.
3. Launch a command line and try natxo asenjo's answer.

It might not help, for the reason MDMarra specified in his comment, but it's worth a try.